# Show entries authored by certain zoo visitor member on their profile page

Tags: channel-entries, zoo-visitor, author

I've got a profile page for each of my zoo visitor members and on there I want a list of all the entries they've written. My URL is /careers/network/julie-alchin with 'julie-alchin' being the {visitor:url_title}. I don't know if I can use that segment_3 in anyway in the channel entries tag?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, Julie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details url_title="{segment_3}"} 
     {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" author_id="{member_id}"}
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {body}
     {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

But by performance I would choose query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT author_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE url_title = '{segment_3}'"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" author_id="{author_id}"}
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {body}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked. The first one didn't because it pulled the {title} from the zoo visitor entries. Thanks